# Unfortunately, <App Name> has stopped

Tags: android

I know there are many instances of this problem already, but I can't seem to find an answer that is specific for my circumstances. I have been following a tutorial I have seen online, and many of the feedbacks say it worked for them. Upon running the emulator shows the screen with the background, but then crashes with the error message "Unfortunately, Sabre1 has stopped."
Here is my .java file code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String jsonResult;
    private String url = "localhost/foldername/connection php"; //-my connection string in .php
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        accessWebService();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Async Task to access the web
     private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
       try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
          response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
       }

       catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
      }

     private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
           String rLine = "";
           StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
           BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

           try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             answer.append(rLine);
            }
           }

           catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           return answer;
          }

     @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       ListDrwaer();
      }
     }// end async task

     public void accessWebService() {
      JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
      // passes values for the urls string array
      task.execute(new String[] { url });
     }

     // build hash set for list view
     public void ListDrwaer() {
      List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

      try {
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("login_tb");

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String Fname = jsonChildNode.optString("Fname");
        String Mname = jsonChildNode.optString("Mname");
        String Lname = jsonChildNode.optString("Lname");
        String number = jsonChildNode.optString("Employee_ID");
        String outPut = Fname + "-" + Mname + "-" + Lname + "-" + number;
        employeeList.add(createEmployee("employees", outPut));
       }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

      SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new String[] { "employees" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        }

     private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
      HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
      return employeeNameNo;
     }

}
```

Here is my .xml file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/adservewelcome">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here are my logcat errors

```
12-20 04:08:04.360: E/memtrack(2466): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-20 04:08:04.360: E/android.os.Debug(2466): failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-20 04:13:13.410: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.420: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.430: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.430: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.430: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.430: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.430: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.500: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.500: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-20 04:13:13.600: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
12-20 04:13:21.960: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.020: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.140: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.160: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.170: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.240: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.240: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.250: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.270: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.280: E/SoundPool(1820): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
12-20 04:13:22.940: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:22.940: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:22.940: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:22.950: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:22.950: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1603666533
12-20 04:13:22.950: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
12-20 04:13:22.950: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:22.950: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540): Process: com.example.sabre1, PID: 2540
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at com.example.sabre1.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:105)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at com.example.sabre1.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:90)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at com.example.sabre1.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-20 04:13:38.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 04:13:38.350: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.360: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.360: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.360: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.360: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1603666533
12-20 04:13:38.360: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
12-20 04:13:38.370: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
12-20 04:13:38.370: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Please help. I've been stuck for days. Thanks.

Comment: what is in that line at com.example.sabre1.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:105)

Comment: Check line number 105 of your MainActivity.java.

Comment: Which is your `line 105` ?

Comment: You need to learn how to read logcat. The error is written there.

Comment: @Saint-Clair check out my answer and try accordingly.

Comment: This is really weird. My MainActivity.java only has 135 lines. Does that mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your response. you are not getting the response from the server in `doInBackground`.

on this method (`onPostExecute`) before calling the method check this validation.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (jsonResult != null && jsonResult.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    ListDrwaer();               
    }
}
```

**UPDATED CODE :**

and in `doInBackground` as it is default return type it String then you should do like this instead of declaring global variable for JSON_RESPONSE.

```
// Async Task to access the web
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String mResponse = "";
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            mResponse = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            mResponse = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mResponse = "";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mResponse;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Yon must not refresh views from the doInBackground method.
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null && result.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            ListDrwaer(result);
        }
    }
}// end async task
```

Comment: @Saint-Clair debug and whether you are getting any thing from server or not. and show whatever you are getting.